# Jenkins Python API and Multi-Configuration Projects

Tags: python, jenkins, multi-configuration

I have set up a multi-configuration project in Jenkins and I'm trying to manage those jobs through a command line script. I'm trying to use the jenkinsapi Python module for this. So far I've found how to get my job, but I can't figure out how to get specific build configurations to see if they've succeeded.

```
from jenkinsapi.jenkins import *
jenkins = Jenkins('http://example.org/jenkins')
job = jenkins.get_job('foobar')

# I can get job info here, but I don't know how to access specific configurations
```

Is there anyway to do this? Is each one of the multi-configuration projects a separate "job" or are they all lumped into the same job? I'm going to have to manage a lot of these types of projects in the future, and I want to be able to add a new hardware configuration to the build easily.

Comment: not clear which information you want to fetch and what is unique for your multi-configuration projects

Answer (score 2):

I do not think Python JenkinsAPI is suitable for working with Matrix jobs. Use Groovy scripts via [Groovy Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Groovy+plugin) to tap into [Jenkins Java API](http://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/).

Matrix classes live in [hudson.matrix](http://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/hudson/matrix/package-summary.html) module.

Comment: Is this capable of working with the remote API? Or is the remote API just not capable of dealing with matrix jobs?

Comment: The information about configuration runs is accessible remotely (you can see it via `http://[jenkins_server]/api/xml` in the browser (individual configuration runs will be under /hudson/job/build/run). JenkinsAPI does not deal with it AFAIK (of course, you can add it yourself). In any case, however, that info is 'post-factum' - after the build. Accessing Jenkins via Groovy will have to be done from a job that runs on that Jenkins. However, **that** jobs (or jobs) can be managed remotely via parameters, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Not so clear what you want, give some hints.

If you are not clear what information you can from object `job` in the API, you can use below method to check

**Check the source codes** in github, it is [job.py](https://github.com/salimfadhley/jenkinsapi/blob/master/jenkinsapi/job.py) for your case, also you can use python `dir()` method to see which you can call in `job`

```
>>> from jenkinsapi.jenkins import *
>>> jenkins = Jenkins('http://localhost')
>>> job = jenkins.get_job('foobar')
>>> dir(job)
['RETRY_ATTEMPTS', '__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__getattribute__', '__get
item__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__module__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__s
izeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', '_buildid_for_type', '_config', '_data', '_element_tree', '_get_
config_element_tree', '_mk_json_from_build_parameters', '_poll', '_revmap', '_scm_map', '_scmbranchmap', '_scmurlmap', '
baseurl', 'delete_from_queue', 'disable', 'enable', 'get_build', 'get_build_dict', 'get_build_ids', 'get_build_triggerur
l', 'get_buildnumber_for_revision', 'get_config', 'get_config_xml_url', 'get_data', 'get_delete_url', 'get_description',
 'get_downstream_job_names', 'get_downstream_jobs', 'get_first_build', 'get_first_buildnumber', 'get_jenkins_obj', 'get_
last_build', 'get_last_build_or_none', 'get_last_buildnumber', 'get_last_completed_build', 'get_last_completed_buildnumb
er', 'get_last_failed_buildnumber', 'get_last_good_build', 'get_last_good_buildnumber', 'get_next_build_number', 'get_pa
rams', 'get_params_list', 'get_queue_item', 'get_rename_url', 'get_revision_dict', 'get_scm_branch', 'get_scm_type', 'ge
t_scm_url', 'get_upstream_job_names', 'get_upstream_jobs', 'invoke', 'is_enabled', 'is_queued', 'is_queued_or_running',
'is_running', 'jenkins', 'load_config', 'mk_json_from_build_parameters', 'modify_scm_branch', 'modify_scm_url', 'name',
'poll', 'python_api_url', 'strip_trailing_slash', 'update_config']
>>> print job.get_last_build()
foobar #5
```

**Check the configuration** directly, click REST API in the bottom of your `foobar` job, you can get the job configuration directly like http://example.org/jenkins/job/foobar/api/json?pretty=true

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way I found to dealing with multi / matrix configurations is by loading it as a job. The .../api/python data for a configuration is exactly the same as a normal job. So we can just access it like one with a few changes to the api.

Edit the:
**process_job_folder** function in jenkinsbase.py

and 
**get_full_name_from_url_and_baseurl** in job.py

Either edit the api code or just overwrite the functions. (bit ugly but works ^_^)

I also made a small change to how the names are displayed. This way the naming is more consistent with: jobs, "sub"? jobs and configurations

for example:

Job Name/Job Name/Configuration

```
import urlparse
from jenkinsapi import job
from jenkinsapi import jenkins

def process_job_folder(self, folder, folder_path):
    folder_path += '/job/%s' % folder['name']
    data = self.get_data(self.python_api_url(folder_path),
                         tree='jobs[name,color]')
    result = []
    for job in data.get('jobs', []):
        if 'color' not in job.keys():
            result += self.process_job_folder(job, folder_path)
        else:
            job['url'] = '%s/job/%s' % (folder_path, job['name'])
            ## Added to prevent name conflicts
            job['name'] = folder['name'] + "/" + job['name']
            result.append(job)
            ## Added configuration support
            configData = self.get_data(self.python_api_url(job['url']),
                                       tree='activeConfigurations[name,color,url]')
            for config in configData.get("activeConfigurations", []):
                config['url'] = '%s/%s' % (job['url'], config["name"])
                config["name"] = job['name'] + "/" + config["name"]
                result.append(config)
            ## End of edit
    return result

@staticmethod
def get_full_name_from_url_and_baseurl(url, baseurl):
    """
    Get the full name for a job (including parent folders) from the
    job URL.
    """
    path = url.replace(baseurl, '')
    split = path.split('/')
    ## Ignore /job and empty strings
    split = [urlparse.unquote(part) for part in split[::] if not part in ["", "job"]]
    ## End of edit
    return '/'.join(split)

jenkins.JenkinsBase.process_job_folder = process_job_folder
job.Job.get_full_name_from_url_and_baseurl = get_full_name_from_url_and_baseurl

def get_server_instance():
    jenkins_url = SERVER_URL
    server = jenkins.Jenkins(jenkins_url,
                     username = USERNAME, password = PASSWORD_OR_API_KEY,
                     ssl_verify=False,
                     timeout=50)
    return server

s = get_server_instance()
for j in s.get_jobs():
    print j
```

*Edit:

Now you can do:

```
s = get_server_instance()
myJobName = "foobar/platform=x64"
j = s.get_job(myJobName)

latestBuild = j.get_last_build()
print "Latest build number: ",latestBuild.get_number()
print "\tLatest build status: ",latestBuild.get_status()
```